# Can i have 2 Dialogs in the same "onCreateDialog"?

Tags: android, eclipse, datepicker, timepicker

i have a onCreateDialog setted and i need to put 2 Dialogs (Datepicker and Timepicker) but when i put both of them inside onCreateDialog it only opens the first one which is Datepicker.

Code:

```
    @Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    //date picker
            switch (id) {
                case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
               // set date picker as current date
                    return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,day);
                }
            //time picker
            switch (id) {
                case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
                    //set time picker as current time
                    return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour, minute,false);
                    }
            return null;
}
```

Comment: Show the code related to caller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can, but your `switch` is invalid. Correct syntax of `switch` is:

```
switch( variable ) {
  case value1:
      ...
      break;
  case value X:
      ...
      break;
}
```

and optionally `default` to catch all the other values you do not have explicit `case` for. And you got two switches which is of no use. You correct code would be:

```
AlertDialog myDialog = null;

switch (id) {
  case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
    // set date picker as current date
    myDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,day);
    break;

  case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
    //set time picker as current time
    myDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour, minute,false);
    break;

}

return myDialog;
```

also your IDs have to be unique, but once you fix the `switch`, compiler will show error if you got it set to the same value (because you cannot have more than one `case` for given value).

```
public static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 1;
public static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 2;
```

EDIT: I reworked this a bit again, because I personally dislike more than one exit point from the method - you got many `return`.

Comment: can you please show me in the full code? im really new to this and i tried something here but well, didn't worked just came up many errors

Comment: on "case DATE_DIALOG_ID" and "case TIME_DIALOG_ID" it says duplicated case

Comment: So here is your real culprit. I suspect you got them both assigned the same value (i.e. `1`). It have to be different. So if `DATE_DIALOG_ID` is `1` then make `TIME_DIALOG_ID` set to `2` and you are done.

Comment: OK but how and where do i do change the value?

Comment: see the edit. Simply find the place in your code you defined them and adjust as in my code.

Comment: oh, thanks :D their value was 999 each haha, ok i changed them to 1 and 2. But now the "DatePickerDialog" and "TimePickerDialog" is giving errors like: Create Method (...

Comment: oh nevermind i got why it was wrong, thanks and yes! it is running the way i wanted :D thanks